# ssrs 2008 missing data and preview panes

Tags: reporting-services

im used to working with ssrs 2005. it has 3 panes data,layout,preview
now in 2008 I only have the layout.

what is wrong?
should i install something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the VS08? kb947173
Also, have you checked View->Report Data at the bottom?